# C# Convert json to multiple classes

Tags: c#, json, parsing, serialization

I have a problem. I am trying to parse my json to 2 classes. Here is the json:

```
{
   "user":[
      [
         {
            "Id":"0",
            "Username":"Vreeswijk",
            "ProfilePicture":"media/user/0.png"
         }
      ]
   ],
   "token":[
      [
         {
            "access_token":"myToken1",
            "refresh_token":"myToken2",
            "expires_in":3600,
            "expires_on":1577363756
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

And here are my 2 classes:

```
public class Token
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public int expire_in { get; set; }
    public int expire_on { get; set; }

    public Token() { }
}
```

And here is the user class:

```
public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }

    public User() { }
    public User(string Username, string Password)
    {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;
    }
}
```

Now I want to deserialize the json to those 2 classes.
Here is my code now that works for 1 class only:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var userPropery = jObject["user"] as JArray;
userList= new List<user>();

foreach (var property in userPropery )
{
    var propertyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<user>>(property.ToString());

    userList.AddRange(propertyList);
}
```

How can I make this work for 2 classes in 1 json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe your Json, both user and token are nested Arrays. You can now create Root Class that has both the required properties. For Example

```
public class Root
{
    public List<List<User>> user { get; set; }
    public List<List<Token>> token { get; set; }
}
```

Now, instead of using `JObject.Parse` you could deserialize it directly as

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

To get a flattened user and token list, you can use

```
var userList= root.user.SelectMany(x=>x); 
var tokenList= root.token.SelectMany(x=>x);
```

Comment: When I put the json directly in the Deserializer I get this error: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MyApp.Models.User' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.`

Comment: Hope you have used Json string directly and not a part of it after parsing it as JObject ?

Comment: I parsed nothing into a jobject. I provided the result that I got from the page

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Root` class for your json and add two properties in it with `User` and `Token` classes as required.

```cs
public class Root
{
    public List<List<User>> Users { get; set; }
    public List<List<Token>> Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

Then pass this class in `DeserializeObject` function to deserialize the json.

Comment: Okay, but I don't need to use the List<> because I always get 1 element back. But what do I need to do with this line: `var userPropery = jObject["user"] as JArray;`..... I need both of them now?

Comment: Have you tried using `var tokenPropery = jObject["token"] as JArray;` to deserialize using your existing code ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a class include both `user` and `token`?
If you don't do this, please parse one by one.